# weird rendered colors

Tags: rendering

Weird rendered colors both in viewport shading rendered and also in final rendered image.
Has anyone seem this? I deleted everything now there is only a sun light and a icosphere. before this i was linking some demo characters from blender demo website pages. Like phil and snow character. It happens both eeve or cycles[image: image2]

Comment: Looks a bit like _Color Management_ is set  to  _View Transform_ > _False Color_ instead of _Filmic_.

Comment: holy crap really? thanks. im autist and idiot also.

Comment: No problem. Everyone can be an idiot if they are new to a software. I sometimes make stupid mistakes even after many years working with Blender.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Wow! Well spotted! A brief answer, here, to get accepted and mark the Q as solved?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you have set *View Transform* to *False Color* in the *Render Properties* tab under *Color Management*. Set it back to the default *Filmic*.

[image: false color]